# MAAS - use different preseeds-scripts based on zone or tag

Tags: system-installation, maas, preseed, tag

I would like to use different preseeds-scripts based on the MAAS zone. But I think this isn't possible at the moment, maybe there is another solution how to use different preseeds-scripts based on tags or something similar?

The [documentation](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/development/preseeds.html#user-provided-preseeds) didn't show any example or information if it's possible.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `generic` and `preseed_master` are generated automatically by the template engine [Tempita](http://pythonpaste.org/tempita/) we could access the objects from django / python and decide which parts of a preseed-script is called.

I'm for example created some zones (production, staging) and use different mirrors for the resource that is required. I've modified the `generic` file to add an extra definition:

```
{{def example}}
# set repository based on zone name
#·{{node.zone}}
{{if node.zone.name in {'staging',} }}
d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string deb https://repo.example.com/ubuntu staging/
d-i apt-setup/local0/comment string staging repository
d-i apt-setup/local0/key sting http://repo.example.com/repo.key
{{endif}}
{{if node.zone.name in {'production',} }}
d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string deb https://repo.example.com/ubuntu production/
d-i apt-setup/local0/comment string production repository
d-i apt-setup/local0/key sting http://repo.example.com/repo.key
{{endif}}
d-i apt-setup/local1/repository string deb https://repo.example.com/ubuntu common/
d-i apt-setup/local1/comment string common reposiotry
d-i apt-setup/local1/key sting http://repo.example.com/repo.key
d-i pkgsel/include string git jenkins-slave jenkins-scripts ntp
{{enddef}}
```

This definition could easily called in the `preseed_master` file via:

```
{{self.example}}
```

You could access all node information with the object `node`. All object / module details could be checked in the source code on `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/models/node.py`

Answer (score 0):

For a preseed based on tags, you can do:

```
{{if 'bigDisk' in (node.tag_names())}}
  ...
{{elif 'smallDisk' in (node.tag_names())}}
  ...
{{else}}
  ...
{{endif}}
```

If your 'preseed' part, in wich you use this, is inherited then you can not use the {{inherit "File"}}. At this moment.